# Rate of Heat Loss of Plasma in Space

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics

As space is effectively a vacuum that is roughly steady around 4 K, I'm trying to calculate the rate of heat loss for plasma traveling through space.  The best calculator I could find: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/stefan.html#c3 gave me a result in Watts ($0.4485295898437137 \times 10^8\text{ }\mathrm{Watt}$), which is better than nothing, but honestly it's not a value I can completely comprehend.  Can anyone help me either convert the value of Watts to something more understandable, such as degrees K/sec?  Or if someone can point to another way to calculate a value using similar types of values?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, attributing over $10$ digits to the power loss is quite silly. You've probably got $3$ or $4$ **significant** digits, at the most.

Secondly, for normal$^\dagger$ objects, if the power loss is, say $P$ then the rate of cooling $\dot{T}$ ($\mathrm{K/s}$) obeys:

$$P=mc_p\dot{T}$$

with $m$ the mass of the object and $c_p$ its specific heat capacity.

So:

$$\dot{T}=\frac{P}{mc_p}$$

$^\dagger$ No loss or gain of mass, no exo- or endothermic phase transitions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea what the power loss is, since you've said the value the other calculator generated is wrong.  The specific heat capacity of Xenon is 0.158 J/g K, but I have no idea what the mass of the plasma would be.

Comment: No, I *didn't say* the value of your calculator is wrong at all, only that so many digits is not possible. 3 to 4 sign. digits max, so $0.4485$ for example.

Comment: And the x10^8 was still correct?

Comment: Well, it was YOUR calculation but yes, the $\times 10^8$ is unaffected.

Comment: Can you check my math?  Based on that equation, it seems to come to 1.874 x 10^9 K/s heat loss.  That seems wrong.  Based on that, the plasma wouldn't be able to exist for 5.069 x 10^-6 seconds before all heat was lost.

Comment: It all depends on what value for $mc_p$ you used.

Comment: Cp was 0.158 J/gK
mass was 0.15g

Comment: Your numbers are correct because $mc_p$ is very small compared to $P$.

Comment: But that end result makes no realistic sense, so something must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: No, it makes PERFECT sense: something really small that loses power at a phenomenal rate will cool down very, very quickly. The numbers don't lie.